# Terraform: Iterate over objects where at least one has not a special attribute

Tags: terraform

I try to get the information from a local variable that contains objects, if at least one of the objects has the attribute "assign" with the value "true" ( assign = true ).
My code works, if all of the objects have an attribute "assign" but it fails if any object is missing the attribute.

```
locals {  
  assignments = {
      users = {
        "u1" = {per = ["push"], assign = true}
        "u2" = {per = ["push"], assign = false}
      }
      groups = {
        "gr1" = {per = ["o,l"], assign = true}
        "gr2" = {per = ["o"]}
        "gr3" = {per = ["k"], assign = false}
      }
    }
}

output "atLeastOneAssign" {
  value = anytrue(values(merge(local.assignments.users, local.assignments.groups))[*].assign)
}
```

So because "gr2" is missing the attribute "assign" the whole thing fails with "This object does not have an attribute named "assign"." I tried it with "try" and "can" but nothing worked. It works like expected, if any object has this attribute but it cannot be guaranteed.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior with difficulty accessing optional keys in objects is essentially because of the way Golang serializes objects. We can refactor your output to achieve the desired behavior:

```
output "at_least_one_assign" {
  value = contains([for entity in merge(local.assignments.users, local.assignments.groups) : try(entity.assign, false)], true)
}
```

The `users` and `groups` Map are merged together. The `for` expression iterates over the combined nested Map where the values are the assigned objects. For each iteration, we store the object value in the temporary lambda variable `entity`. We then attempt to access the value for the `assign` key in each `entity`, and use the `try` function to default to a boolean of `false` if no `assign` key exists (exploiting the fact that all we care about here is the existence of `true`). A `list` constructor assembles all of the `for` expression values for `assign` into a `list(bool)`. Finally, the `contains` function asserts if a single `true` is in the list, and returns `true` if so, and `false` otherwise. Essentially, this is equivalent to a return of `true` if any of the `assign` value is `true`, and `false` otherwise. This is the desired behavior.

Comment: Wow. Thanks !!!! Really cool.  It works like expected!